# what is instance in WordPress widget function?

Tags: wordpress, widget

I am beginner at theme development and i want to build a custom widget from scratch but i can't understand what is the purpose of instance parameter and what is there inside it?

```
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

    echo $args['before_widget'];

    if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
        echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ) . $args['after_title'];
    }

    echo '<div class="textwidget">';

    echo esc_html__( $instance['text'], 'text_domain' );

    echo '</div>';

    echo $args['after_widget'];

}
```

Comment: This question belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.com.

But this should explain it: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69757/what-is-this-instance-variable-doing-in-the-widgets-class

Answer (score 0):

`$instance` is a variable repeatedly used within the [WP_Widget](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_widget/) class (and hence also in all child classes). it is just an array with settings for an incarnation of a WordPress widget. This array() gets saved to the DB and retrieved again to be able to save the settings for the different widgets.